# Issue with classpath in Java project

Tags: java, jar, tibco

I'm currently working on a Java project which uses Tibco rendezvous control.

I have the tibrvj.jar file on my `build` path. But I'm not able to see the classes which are there in the package "`com.tibco.tibrv`".

This package is in the jar which is on my build path.

When I try to open the class in that package , the message displayed on class editor is : "**Source not found. the jar file tibrvj.jar has no source attachment**".

Is there anything that could be done to set it right ?

Comment: Please consider changing the heading to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an IDE specific message. Which IDE are you using?

The jar in your classpath only contains the java classes (bytecode) and not the source files (.java files). It looks like you are trying to open the class in your IDE/editor. Since you do not have the java files corrsponding to these classes, the editor is comlaining.

As these are Tibco specific classes, the only option is to "decompile" the classes to see the corresponding java code. Consider using a decompiler like [DJ Java Decompiler](http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "I'm not able to see the classes." If you mean you're getting build failures, that's possibly a matter of not *actually* having it properly in your build path (how are you building?) or maybe not having the right imports.

If you mean you can't see the source code, you'll need to get hold of it somehow (is Tibco open source?) and then configure your IDE so that it knows where the source is. Of course you don't need to source just to be able to build your app which uses Tibco.

If you could give more information about exactly which problem you're facing, along with what IDE you're using (if any) we could probably help more.